# Reading mail RTFbody fails with error 'not implemented'

Tags: vba, outlook

I have code that reads mail to generate a task with the mail's content.

In a few cases this hits a problem, when reading the RTFbody from the mail, saying "not implemented".

Can I test against this? Like WHEN  IS NULL ... which checks if a variable has appropriate content.

[image]

```vb
Sub CreateTempTaskFromMail()

    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set oMail = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
        
    Dim s, sNr As String
    s = oMail.subject
    
    Dim oTask As Outlook.TaskItem
    Set oTask = CreateTaskWithTempFolder(s, False)  ' Function creating and returing task
        
    oTask.RTFBody = oMail.RTFBody
    
End sub
```

I tried to test several ways if RTFbody has a problem. All of these approaches throw an error.

```
If oMail.RTFBody Is Nothing Then Stop
If IsError(oMail.RTFBody) Then Stop
If IsMissing(oMail.RTFBody) Then Stop
If IsEmpty(oMail.RTFBody) Then Stop
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function

Comment: Are you sure you got a MailItem object here?

Comment: Yes - I checked to have a Mailitem, indeed. It must be as I create the item using Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem

Answer (score 1):

If there is absolutely no real solution then

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateTempTaskFromMail()

Dim oObj As Object
Dim oMail As mailItem
Dim oTask As TaskItem

Dim s As String

Set oObj = ActiveInspector.currentItem

If oObj.Class = olMail Then

    Set oMail = oObj
    s = oMail.subject
    
    Set oTask = CreateTaskWithTempFolder(s, False)  ' Function creating and returing task
    
    ' If you absolutely cannot determine the problem
    ' https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling#On_Error_Resume_Next
    On Error Resume Next
    
    oTask.RTFBody = oMail.RTFBody
    
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Error was bypassed using a technique that is to be avoided."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Consider mandatory AND as soon as possible
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    oTask.Display

Else

    Debug.Print "not a mailitem"
    
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Before accessing the `RTFBody` property in the code I'd suggest checking the item's type first to make sure such property exists for a specific item type:

```
If TypeOf item Is MailItem Then
  ' do whatever you need with RTFBody here
End If
```

Or

```
If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
 ' do whatever you need with RTFBody here
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Office 2016 product, you should update office. It is early office 2016 build's bug.